# Privileged access to specific commands in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I’m running a bash srcipt using “sudo script.sh” beacause some of the commands inside script requires privileged access. How can I remove sudo while running the script but give access to commands inside the script?

Comment: Sigh... [bash drop sudo in script](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+drop+sudo+in+script). Among the questions and answers there are two different strategies discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the script with `sudo`, use `sudo` within the script for those specific commands.

The first command will prompt the user for their password. But `sudo` keeps an authentication cache, so it won't ask again for several minutes on the same terminal. As long as the script doesn't go too long between commands that need privilege, it shouldn't ask multiple times.

Comment: Thanks....Can I remove a “sudo required command” from a for loop and call it from another script

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but why would it make a difference which script it's in?

Comment: I want to create script only with specific commands that require sudo

Comment: What does that have to do with a `for` loop? Maybe you should ask a new question that shows the details of what you're asking about.

Comment: You can put `sudo script2.sh` inside `script.sh`. Everything in `script2.sh` will be run as root.

Comment: In my for loop,there is one command requires sudo but others don’t

Comment: `for blah; do command; command; sudo command; command; command; done`

Comment: Exactly I want to call another script with Sudo script2.sh and I want all the sudo required commands in that script

Comment: How is that different from what you asked in the original question?

Comment: I have a script with all commands...I wanna divide it in to 2 scripts....one wth sudo required commands and other that don’t require sudo

Comment: In the process of doing that, I have a for loop with several commands that don’t require sudo but one requires sudo

Comment: Isn't that what I showed above?

Comment: `for ...; do plaincommand; plaincommand; sudo privileged_script.sh; plaincommand; plaincommand; done`

Comment: Sorry for bugging you....I want that specific command in the for loop in another script

Comment: That's what `privileged_script.sh` is.

Comment: Thank for your patience

Comment: I have to go now. If you still don't get it, write a new question with more details.

Comment: pluse uno for tech support ;- )  (and of course a helpful answer).